# How to seperate the string with carriage return in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have some strings to parse in python 3, below are some example:

```
str1 = 'JohnDoe\n  \n(1357)\n\n\n\n\n    SteveH\n  \n(1387)'
str2 = 'Phisher\r\n  \n(1029)\n\n\n\n\n\r\n    Alex201807\r\n  \n(1053)'
```

I need a simple way to retrieve:

```
JohnDoe 1357 SteveH 1387 from str1
Phisher 1029 Alex201807 1053 from str2
```

My python experience is limited, can anyone enlighten? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your attempts so far?

Comment: something like `str1.split("\r\n")[0].strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
str1=' '.join(str1.split())
```

Explanation:

```py
>>> str1 = 'JohnDoe\n  \n(1357)\n\n\n\n\n    SteveH\n  \n(1387)'
>>> str1.split()
['JohnDoe', '(1357)', 'SteveH', '(1387)']
>>> ' '.join(str1.split())
'JohnDoe (1357) SteveH (1387)'
>>> ' '.join(str1.split()).replace('(','').replace(')','')
'JohnDoe 1357 SteveH 1387'
```

Comment: Thanks, any easy way to get the two numbers? other than `.lstrip('(').rstrip(')')`

Comment: `' '.join(str1.split()).replace('(','').replace(')','')`

Comment: Check my answer below, it gives you both the expected string and the numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace all whitespace characters with spaces

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = 'JohnDoe\n  \n(1357)\n\n\n\n\n    SteveH\n  \n(1387)'
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str1)
'JohnDoe (1357) SteveH (1387)'
>>> str2 = 'Phisher\r\n  \n(1029)\n\n\n\n\n\r\n    Alex201807\r\n  \n(1053)'
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str2)
'Phisher (1029) Alex201807 (1053)'
```

Then do it again if you want to remove the parenthesis

Comment: Thanks. How do I further get the two numbers?

Comment: Thanks. seems too cumbersome, I've decided to use the simple `.lstrip('(').rstrip(')')` for it which works for me.

Comment: That only removes from the start at end of the whole string... For example, you just get `JohnDoe (1357) SteveH (1387`

Comment: true, kind of multi steps, with `str1.split()` I have a list of `['JohnDoe', '(1357)', 'SteveH', '(1387)']`, then from the list I apply `.lstrip('(').rstrip(')')`

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get both expected string and numbers too

```
import re
str1 = 'JohnDoe\n  \n(1357)\n\n\n\n\n    SteveH\n  \n(1387)'
str2 = 'Phisher\r\n  \n(1029)\n\n\n\n\n\r\n    Alex201807\r\n  \n(1053)'

def parse_string(text):
    #Replace \r, \n, ( and )
    for char in ['\r','\n','(',')']:
        text = text.replace(char,"")
    #Replace multiple whitespaces with one
    text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip()
    return text

def get_num_from_string(text):
    p = re.compile(r'\d+.\d+')  # Compile a pattern to capture int values
    nums = [int(i) for i in p.findall(text)]  # Convert strings to int
    return nums
#JohnDoe 1357 SteveH 1387
#[1357, 1387]
#Phisher 1029 Alex201807 1053
#[1029, 201807, 1053]
```

Comment: Thanks, as the strings always come with number in the format of (nnnn), I decided to go with the simpler way like `.lstrip('(').rstrip(')')`, really appreciate you and others posting here.

Comment: Sure no problem, but do upvote my answer if it helped you